# Click on Element is not working in appium using codeceptJS

Tags: webdriver-io, appium-android, codeceptjs

Im facing an issue while automating a click on element in virtual Tab android system using Appium & CodeceptJS. when i run the test, i got this error :

ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP meth
od that is not supported by the mapped resource

This is my code :

```
I.click('#com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button');
```

Any idea please ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check as to which helper you are using. If you are using Webdriver helper, then there is a chance that you get above error. Make sure you are using Appium helper and only along with its capabilities.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30304821)